# Unexpected compound result from a foreach loop

Tags: foreach, append, tcl

The following snippet is processing a UTF8-encoded text file (building HL7 segments for hospital data, FYI):

```
set linecounter 0
set newmsg ""

foreach line [split $data \n] {
    incr linecounter
    set seg [append "OBX|"  $linecounter "|" [string trimright $line] "||||||V" \n]
    lappend newmsg $seg
}

echo "This is the new message: " $newmsg
```

If I echo out each `$seg` inside the loop, I get each individual line in the text file, like so (file content of course):

```
line1
line2
line3
etc...
```

Once done with the loop however, `$newmsg` reads as:

```
line1

line1
line2

line1
line2
line3
etc...
```

I have changed `lappend` to `append` inside the loop, `set $seg` to `""` after appending it to `$newmsg` inside the loop, all to no avail. Thoughts?

Comment: I think you don't understand what `append` does.

Comment: Thanks for being rude. I think you don't understand what a request for help is; at least you're correct that I am fairly new to TCL syntax/behavior.

Comment: I think you could easily have got what you wanted without using commands to create `$seg`, by that I mean you probably could have used `set seg "OBX|$linecounter|[string trimright $line]||||||V"` and when printing `$newmsg`, you would then use `echo "This is the new message: " [join $newmsg \n]`.

Comment: `string cat` would be what you'd prefer to `append`, but that's not available unless you've got a very modern version of Tcl.

Comment: @JohnDouet Sorry, I did not have much time so I wrote something to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you are looking for something like this:

```
set data "hello\nworld\nits\nme\nalex"

set linecounter 0
set newmsg ""

foreach line [split $data \n] {
    incr linecounter
    set seg "OBX|$linecounter|[string trimright $line]||||||V\n"
    append newmsg $seg
}

puts "This is the new message: $newmsg"
```

This will create string with \n line breaks inside it.
Sample output for this code:

```
This is the new message: OBX|1|hello||||||V
OBX|2|world||||||V
OBX|3|its||||||V
OBX|4|me||||||V
OBX|5|alex||||||V
```

You got strange output due to two reasons:
1. append requires variable name as first param. So OBX| was its name and its content was grown during loop.
2. echo list used to wrap its items with {}

Comment: And better is `append newmsg $seg`

Comment: Thanks Alex - that's closer, but I am getting:

'OBX|1|  <line break here>

SOUTHERN  <line break here>

MEDICAL  <line break here>

CORPORATION||||||V

Comment: Final code simply used lappend instead of append:  lappend newmsg $seg.  Thanks for your help!